# Deleting nested property in javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have a JS object like this:

```
var tenants = {
    'first': {
        'name': 'first',
        'expired': 1
    },
    'second': {
        'name': 'second'
    }
}
```

And I'd like to delete the 'expired' property of tenant 'first', should I just do this?

```
delete tenants['first']['expired'];
```

Note: this question is more specific than the question: [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object), in that my question focuses on the 'nested' part.

Comment: Short answer: Yes. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes. That would work.

`delete tenants['first']['expired'];` or `delete tenants.first.expired;`.

If you are deleting it only because you wanted to exclude it from `JSON.stringify()`, you can also just set it to `undefined`, like `tenants['first']['expired'] = undefined;`

Answer (score 17):

If your app is using lodash, then `_.unset` is a safe way for deleting nested properties. You can specify nested keys without worrying about their existence.

```
let games = { 'hitman': [{ 'agent': { 'id': 47 } }] };
_.unset(games, 'hitman[0].agent.id');
_.unset(games, 'hitman[0].muffin.cupcake'); // won't break
```

further reading: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#unset

Comment: I knew lodash had something but could not find what I was looking for.  Thanks for putting up a standard solution instead of a custom function.

Comment: I love how lodash takes away all the anxiety of nested data operations.

Answer (score 16):

If the property you want to delete is stored in a string, you can use this function

```
function deletePropertyPath (obj, path) {

  if (!obj || !path) {
    return;
  }

  if (typeof path === 'string') {
    path = path.split('.');
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i++) {

    obj = obj[path[i]];

    if (typeof obj === 'undefined') {
      return;
    }
  }

  delete obj[path.pop()];
};
```

Example Usage

```
var tenants = {
    'first': {
        'name': 'first',
        'expired': 1
    },
    'second': {
        'name': 'second'
    }
}

var property = 'first.expired';    
deletePropertyPath(tenants, property);
```

Comment: This doesn't work well with arrays has it leave a "empty" value at the removed array index.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to delete a property with a particular name in an *arbitrarily deep object*, I would recommend that you use a battle-tested library.  You can use [DeepDash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepdash), an extension to Lodash.

```
  // Recursively remove any "expired" properties
  _.eachDeep(e, (child, prop, parent, ctx):boolean => {
    if (prop === 'expired') {
      delete parent[prop];
      return false; // per docs, this means do not recurse into this child
    }
    return true;
  });
```

And if you would rather have a new copy (rather than mutating the existing object), DeepDash also has an `omitDeep` function you can use that will return the new object.

Answer (score 3):

I came up with this:

```
const deleteByPath = (object, path) => {
  let currentObject = object
  const parts = path.split(".")
  const last = parts.pop()
  for (const part of parts) {
    currentObject = currentObject[part]
    if (!currentObject) {
      return
    }
  }
  delete currentObject[last]
}
```

Usage:

```
deleteByPath({ "a" : { "b" : true }},"a.b")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the path of the key separated by `.`, say `first.expired` in your case, you can do `deleteKey(tenants, 'first.expired')`:

```js
const deleteKey = (obj, path) => {
    const _obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
    const keys = path.split('.');

    keys.reduce((acc, key, index) => {
        if (index === keys.length - 1) {
            delete acc[key];
            return true;
        }
        return acc[key];
    }, _obj);

    return _obj;
}

let tenants = {
    'first': {
        'name': 'first',
        'expired': 1
    },
    'second': {
        'name': 'second'
    }
};

const PATH_TO_DELETE = 'first.expired';

tenants = deleteKey(tenants, PATH_TO_DELETE);
console.log('DELETE SUCCESSFUL:', tenants);
```

Answer (score 0):

With modern JS you can simple do it this way:

```js
const tenants = {
  first: {
    name: 'first',
    expired: 1
  },
  second: {
    name: 'second'
  }
}

delete tenants?.first?.expired;
delete tenants?.second?.expired;
delete tenants?.third?.expired;

console.log(tenants);
```

By using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) you're able to safely **try** to remove nested properties on objects that might not exist.

Check the mdn site to check browser compatibility

NOTE: Optional chaining does also [works with braces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#optional_chaining_with_expressions)